# Correct use of 'not be able to'

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

> In practice, it is very rare not be able to send this..

Could you please tell me if the order of the words in `not be able to` is correct?
Also, should I add `to` before `not` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two infinitives, *be* and *send*, in the ungrammatical sentence

- **It is rare not **be** able to **send** this.*

and both infinitives need a *to* to mark them. *Send* already has *to*, but *be* does not.
That's what makes it ungrammatical.

The *to* can be inserted either before or after *not*;
both of the following are correct:

- *It is rare **to** not be able to send this.*
- *It is rare not **to** be able to send this.*

Comment: You are right that both word orders are correct, but the second is very much more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+to+be+able+to%2Cto+not+be+able+to%2C+to+be+unable+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20to%20be%20able%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20not%20be%20able%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20unable%20to%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Only in printed materials. In speech they're about even, or possibly the other way.

Comment: I did the NGram before you answered, but I wasn't sure why I was looking at **to not be able to**. You are right: that version is more common in spoken english.

Comment: @JavaLatte: [*I **don't want** to have to*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=want+to+not+have+to%2Cwant+not+to+have+to%2Cdon%27t+want+to+have+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwant%20to%20not%20have%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwant%20not%20to%20have%20to%3B%2Cc0) point out that according to NGrams *nobody* starts a sentence like that. Apparently everyone except me uses either *I want to not have to* or *I want not to have to*, but I must say either of those would strike me as ***very*** "strange" in the context of my first sentence here.

Comment: More likely in writing, but not that common in speech. They don't have the right rhythm.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "to" in front of "be able" as you suggest as the
construction requires the infinitive "to be", whether negative or positive.

The sentence has to read: "In practice, it is very rare not to be able to send this.